# How to display image or video file from AWS S3 bucket on my website using PHP

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to display images from my AWS S3 bucket using PHP, I can succesfully retrieve the object Key and display it on my website using PHP but I dont know how to display the file it self.

```
    require './vendor/autoload.php';

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    // AWS Info
    $bucketName = '#';
    $IAM_KEY = '#';
    $IAM_SECRET = '#';

    // Connect to AWS
    try {

        $s3 = S3Client::factory(
            array(
                'credentials' => array(
                    'key' => $IAM_KEY,
                    'secret' => $IAM_SECRET,
                ),
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region'  => 'eu-west-2'
            )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());

    } $result = $s3->listObjects(array('Bucket' => $bucketName)); 
    
echo "Keys retrieved!\n";

foreach ($result['Contents'] as $object) {

 echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
  echo '<img src="'.$result .'">'

}
```

Any help or points in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

One should have a web server to serve the images.

1. Use the S3 native website support - make the bucket public - very easy.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html
   But be mindful that all of the objects in the bucket become public.
   If one wants to protect the content, use presigned URLs
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html
2. Set up CloudFront in front of the S3 to act as CDN for fast content delivery.
   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/
   CloudFront also supports predesigned URLs so that one can protect the content.
3. Maybe the heaviest and error-prone; copy the objects locally on the server or to a shared file system (like EFS) and serve them from the same server with the php. While this is an option, I would not generally recommend it.

The usual approach is the have a CloudFront routing.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/deliver-your-apps-dynamic-content-using-amazon-cloudfront-getting-started-template/

a) Dynamic content to the web server with PHP (there might be many servers behind an ALB for scaling or a single server)

b) Static content to S3